# unable to including ajax file

Tags: c#, html, ajax, visual-studio-2010

Im getting this error message from IE when trying to set up Ajax

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Ajax' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 13:       <!-- Register the ajax handler -->
Line 14:       <add verb="POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx"
Line 15:            type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax" />
Line 16:     </httpHandlers>
Line 17:
```

The file I have added to my bin folder is AjaxPro.dll, and I have added the above code to the config file.

can anyone tell me how to fix this?

P.S Ive been using this as a guide 
[MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479042.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

Add a reference to the AjaxPro.2.dll

(for the .NET 1.1 Framework use AjaxPro.dll)

Add following lines to your web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET" path="ajaxpro/*.ashx" 
             type="AjaxPro.AjaxHandlerFactory, AjaxPro.2"/>
    </httpHandlers>

...
```

for the .NET 1.1 Framework use AjaxPro.dll
Add following lines to your web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
          <add verb="POST,GET" path="ajaxpro/*.ashx"
                 type="AjaxPro.AjaxHandlerFactory, AjaxPro"/>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue. currently my webconfig is

```
  <system.webServer>
         <handlers>
              <add name="AjaxPro" verb="POST,GET" path="ajaxpro/*.ashx" type="AjaxPro.AjaxHandlerFactory, AjaxPro.2"/>
          </handlers>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```

and it is working fine.